# Controller function called twice in angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm currently getting to grips with angular and I'm a complete new guy to it, I've put together a jsfiddle for the issue.

But in short I'm not sure why my function attached to the angular scope is called twice.

Script

```
var registrationModule = angular.module("registrationModule", []);
registrationModule.controller("NavigationController",  function ($scope) {
    $scope.menuItems = [{ text: 'Home'}];
    alert("hi");
    $scope.getClass = function (path) {
        alert("getClass");
        return "frank";
    };
});
```

HTML

```
<body ng-app="registrationModule">
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-responsive-collapse">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" ng-controller="NavigationController">
        hi {{ getClass(); }} butcher
    </ul>
</div>
</body>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6F55K/1/

Any tips?

Comment: it's the angularjs digest cycle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Angular digest loop is built to work this way. Any expressions in your view will be executed **at least once**.

When the view is compiled it will call your `getClass()` function to get a value, then it will run the digest loop again to see if anything has changed since its previous call. This is how it knows that your view is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

Noel's answer didn't work for me. How about changing the function so it sets a variable?

```
registrationModule.controller("NavigationController",  function ($scope) {
    $scope.menuItems = [{ text: 'Home'}];
    alert("hi");
    $scope.setClass = function (path) {
        alert("setClass");
        $scope.class = "frank";
    };
});
```

Check out this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6F55K/3/

Comment: I thought it was an issue with route registration... it didn't work for me either :)